# Add new line using /n in text variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

I have a variable in my view printed on screen as

```
<%= comment.comment %>
```

but the output has many new line characters (`\n`).

How do I get it to actually print new lines whenever we have a `\n` with `comment.comment` output?

Comment: vm 2/2\n37) sent matrix report to JPD scraping LR15-001 3/2 WL \n\nTo Do's:\n- F/U w/ Jason @ Grubb riser right size 2/3?\n- F/U w/ JPD on drawings for vessels for semiautomatic (need these to make custom spacer plate) 2/3\n- F/U w/ Bob on availability on L&L training for operators on installation 2/3\n- F/U w/ Matt/Bryan on spacer plate for automatic vessels 2/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= comment.comment.gsub(/\n/, '<br />') %>
```

Else you can also use [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format). Here:

```
<%= simple_format(comment.comment) %>
```

Comment: 2.2.0 :002 > ticket.summary
 => "req for update on lab report, Matt confirmed will have spacer plate quote sent as soon as Bryan @ Parker gets power back, CH left Bob @ PECO vm 2/2\\n37) sent matrix report to JPD & PECO scraping LR15-001 3/2 WL \\n\\nTo Do's:\\n- F/U w/ Jason @ Grubb riser right size 2/3?\\n- F/U w/ JPD on drawings for vessels for semiautomatic (need these to make custom spacer plate) 2/3\\n- F/U w/ Bob on availability on L&L training for operators on installation 2/3\\n- F/U w/ Matt/Bryan on spacer plate for automatic vessels 2/3"

Comment: 2.2.0 :003 > ticket.summary.gsub(/\n/, '<br />')
 => "req for update on lab report, Matt confirmed will have spacer plate quote sent as soon as Bryan @ Parker gets power back, CH left Bob @ PECO vm 2/2\\n37) sent matrix report to JPD & PECO scraping LR15-001 3/2 WL \\n\\nTo Do's:\\n- F/U w/ Jason @ Grubb riser right size 2/3?\\n- F/U w/ JPD on drawings for vessels for semiautomatic (need these to make custom spacer plate) 2/3\\n- F/U w/ Bob on availability on L&L training for operators on installation 2/3\\n- F/U w/ Matt/Bryan on spacer plate for automatic vessels 2/3"

Comment: same thing. isn't working, although `simple_format` places the entire output in its own paragraph tags

Comment: @CameronAziz Looking at your example string, you should try this: `<%= simple_format(comment.comment.gsub("\\n","\n")) %>`

Comment: but this works:   2.2.0 :008 > ticket.summary.gsub(/n/, '<br />')
 => "req for update o<br /> lab report, Matt co<br />firmed will have spacer plate quote se<br />t as soo<br /> as Brya<br /> @ Parker gets power back, CH left Bob @ PECO vm 2/2\\<br />37) se<br />t matrix report to JPD & PECO scrapi<br />g LR15-001 3/2 WL \\<br />\\<br />To Do's:\\<br />- F/U w/ Jaso<br /> @ Grubb riser right size 2/3?\\<br />- F/U w/ JPD o<br /> drawi<br />gs for vessels for semiautomatic (<br />eed these to make custom spacer plate) 2/3\\<br />

Comment: I got `gsub` to work by making a variable `<% new_line = '\n' %>` and then `<%= raw comment.comment.gsub(new_line, '<br />') %>`

Answer (score 0):

Its rendering HTML. So you need to convert the newlines into html tag br. 
Try simple_format http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

Answer (score 0):

HTML interprets newlines as spaces except in elements those where CSS sets `white-space` to `pre`, `pre-line` or `pre-wrap` (like the `<pre>` element, by default).

Thus, you can do one of the following:

```
<pre><%= comment.comment %></pre>

<style> .with-newlines { white-space: pre } </style>
<div class=".with-newlines"><%= comment.comment %></div>

<%= comment.comment.gsub(/\n/, '<br>') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= comment.comment.dump %>
```